# Unable to import Mule 3 projects into Anypoint v6.4.4

Tags: java, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Receiving errors ([errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eh8v.png)) in Anypoint console when opening Anypoint v6.4.4 right after installing the software. Unable to import Mule 3 projects as well and I believe that is due to these errors. When clicking into the first error in the list in the picture, I receive a detailed explanation of the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:834)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:239)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I currently run Java 11.0.16.1 and have downloaded (but not yet used) Eclipse.
Any type of guidance on this is really appreciated

Reinstalling Anypoint and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio 6.x does not support any other version of Java to startup than JDK 8. This is mentioned in the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-6.6-with-3.9.4-runtime-update-site-8-release-notes#software-requirements). That page actually says it supports only the AdoptOpenJDK 8 distribution.

After Studio starts with JDK 8 it can execute Mule applications with Java 7 or Java 8, depending of the version of Mule runtime. All Mule versions that support Java 7 are EOL at this time.